# Numpy array multiplication of LDL^T factorization of symmetric matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Suppose I have an "LDL^T" decomposition of a symmetric, positive-semidefinite matrix A (`numpy` array), and I would like to multiply all factors together to obtain A.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Currently, I am doing (D is available as "vector"):
    `np.dot(np.dot(L, np.diag(D)), L.T)`,
which is quite obviously a bad solution.

Comment: @Divakar Of course, already late over here^^.

Comment: Note that LDL^T does not have necessarily 1x1 blocks on the diagonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could use `elementwise multiplication` and then `matrix-multiplication`. This basically replaces `np.dot(L, np.diag(D))` with a direct `element-wise multiplication` for hopefully some speedup. So, with it, the implementation would become -

```
(L*D).dot(L.T)
```

**Approach #2**

Another approach could be with `np.einsum` to do all those things in one-go, like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,j,kj->ik',L,D,L)
```

---

**Runtime test**

```
In [303]: L = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,1000))

In [304]: D = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))

In [305]: %timeit np.dot(np.dot(L, np.diag(D)), L.T)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.87 s per loop

In [306]: %timeit (L*D).dot(L.T)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop

In [307]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,j,kj->ik',L,D,L)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.71 s per loop
```

Comment: Awesome, I think approach #1 is fastest (quickly checked some timings but no formal benchmarking). I thought element-wise refers to really elements and not multiplying each column by the respective element in the right hand vector.

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking. I think relative performance will crucially depend on the dimensions, and the second approach will be increasingly favorable as compared to the first.

Comment: @Dominik It's hard to choose I guess as app#1 does matrix-mult and this problem is essentially based on it. Though the negative aspect with app#1 is creating the intermediate array on which app#2 shines. I guess with bigger arrays, `einsum` might be better given the memory efficiency.